# Drupal 7 - New template for other pages

Tags: templates, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I've tried using the page-node-2.tpl.php but it hasn't worked...
Is there something I'm missing?

I'm new to Drupal, but I think it might have something to do with not having a template.php in my themes directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://drupal.org/node/1089656 for template file name conventions.  Note that there are two dashes (`--`) in between `page` and `node` and `2`.

Also remember to clear your cache so that Drupal recognizes the new files and/or paths.

Comment: Thanks! But I still can't get the thing working... My URL is like this `www.mysite.co.uk/new/node/2` (Drupal is installed in the 'new' directory) and my file is `page--node--2.tpl.php`

Any more suggestions?

Comment: @jonathandey where did you put the `page--node--2.tpl.php` file?  You need to put it in your theme.  If you don't have your own theme/subtheme, you need to create on otherwise the tpl file will not be picked up.

Comment: I have put it in my sub folder with themes

Comment: @jonathandey You can't just put a file in a subfolder of themes.  All tpl files must belong to a theme and in order for it to be used, it must belong to the theme that you are using (the active theme).  So your tpl file should go into `/sites/all/themes/themeName/page--node--2.tpl.php`

Comment: @jonathandey and you have that particular theme enabled and set as the default?